# Are there any scholarly critiques of Edward Feser's work?

Tags: reference-request, theology, philosophy-of-religion, atheism, christianity

Have there been any critiques of Feser in academia, particularly philosophy of religion? I'd also like to see if there have been critiques of Aristotelian-Thomism which is what Feser's framework is for two of his arguments in his book, "Five Proofs for Existence of God."

Recently I know that Graham Oppy, has published a journal "On Stage One of Feser's Aristotelian Proof" which he critiques not only his Aristotelian proof, but his Neo-Platonic and Rationalist proof as well. However I was wondering if anyone else has taken a shot at him.

Answer (score 4):

The scholarly material I have come across is in academic journals :

1.Five Proofs of the Existence of God by Edward Feser
Review by: Ricardo Barroso Batista
Revista Portuguesa de Filosofia, T. 74, Fasc. 1, Pierre Duhem e Ernst Mach: Ciência e Filosofia / Pierre Duhem and Ernst Mach: Science and Philosophy (2018), pp. 333-338.

2.The Last Superstition: A Refutation of the New Atheism by Edward Feser
Review by: Michael O'Halloran
The Review of Metaphysics, Vol. 62, No. 4 (Jun., 2009), pp. 926-928.

3.Scholastic Metaphysics: A Contemporary Introduction by Edward FESER
Review by: D. Q. McInerny
The Review of Metaphysics, Vol. 68, No. 3 (MARCH 2015), pp. 653-654.

4.End and Agent (pp. 92-106)
From: **Aquinas** on Virtue: A Causal Reading
NICHOLAS AUSTIN
Georgetown University Press (2017).

5.Reply to Critics
John Kekes
The Good Society, Vol. 15, No. 2 (2006), pp. 30-34.

6.THE ONE AND THE MANY: THE ONTOLOGY OF SCIENCE IN ARISTOTLE AND THOMAS
**AQUINAS**
Author(s): CURTIS L. HANCOCK
Source: The Review of Metaphysics, Vol. 69, No. 2 (DECEMBER 2015), pp. 233-259: footnotes 6 & 8.

I hope these references will be of help.

Comment: #1 only seems to be available at https://www.publicacoesfacfil.pt/product.php?id_product=1087 but the others can be read online if you register for a free jstor account -- #2 at https://www.jstor.org/stable/40387780 and #3 at https://www.jstor.org/stable/24636666 and #4 at https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/j.ctt1t89k5h.11.pdf and #5 at https://www.jstor.org/stable/25702816 and #6 at https://www.jstor.org/stable/24636479

Comment: These are helpful  thank you very much. I'll see if I can get my hands on these.